# How can i three-dimensional relationship query by laravel eloquent ORM?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I Three-dimensional query by laravel eloquent ORM? There are four tables such as "buyers", "products", "orders" and "purchases" and four models "buyer", "Products", "Orders" and "Purchases". 
Table structure below

buyers Table

```
id --- name --- email
1 ---- John --- john@example.com
2 ---- Kelly -- kelly@example.com
3 ---- Chery -- chery@example.com
```

products Table:

```
id --- name ---- quantity ---- price
1 ---- Apple --- 5Kg --------- 10$
2 ---- Orange -- 10kg -------- 11$
3 ---- Grapes -- 20kg -------- 15$
```

orders Table:

```
id --- buyer_id --- status
1 ---- 1 ----------- 0
2 ---- 2 ----------- 1
3 ---- 3 ----------- 0
```

purchases Table:

```
id --- order_id ---- product_id --- price --- quantity --- total_price
1 ---- 1 ----------- 2 ------------ 11$ ----- 2Kg -------- 22$
2 ---- 1 ----------- 1 ------------ 10$ ----- 1Kg -------- 10$
3 ---- 1 ----------- 3 ------------ 15$ ----- 5Kg -------- 75$
4 ---- 2 ----------- 1 ------------ 10$ ----- 3kg -------- 30$
5 ---- 2 ----------- 2 ------------ 11$ ----- 4kg -------- 44$
6 ---- 2 ----------- 3 ------------ 15$ ----- 3kg -------- 45$
```

Now I want to query all orders by laravel eloquent with product name, not query builders.

```
$orders = Order::where('status', 0)->...........??
```

Please help me how can I have done it by laravel eloquent query. it's possible or not. if it is possible then help me, please.

Comment: Yes. The above scenario is possible. But i suggest you to read from here. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: good but how can I get all data such as buyer name and all purchase with the product name in one query?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to query all orders by laravel eloquent

Could you be more specific about what you exactly need?

In your example you're already querying the orders, and if you have defined the relations in the models, you can already access the related tables.
With eloquent, to query across the relations you can use `->whereHas` [see Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) , and to pass all related info to the object you can use `->with` [see Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Not sure if this can help!

Comment: good but how can I get all data such as buyer name and all purchase with the product name in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't make the same thing in my local environment but I will give you the basic idea of how to get the details of every related data. Confirm that your model has the specified methods

**Buyer.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Buyer extends Model
{

    /**
     * other functions and properties.
     */

    /**
     * Get the orders associated with the buyer.
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'buyer_id')->where('status', 1);
    }
}
```

**Order.php**

```
class Order extends Model
{

    /**
     * other functions and properties.
     */

    /**
     * Get the purchases associated with the Order.
     */
    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase', 'order_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the buyer belongs to the Order.
     */
    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Buyer', 'buyer_id');
    }
}
```

**Purchase.php**

```
class Purchases extends Model
{    
    /**
     * other functions and properties.
     */

    /**
     * Get the user product belongs to the Purchase.
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the user product belongs to the Purchase.
     */
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
$buyer_id = 1;
$orders = App\Buyer::where('id', $buyer_id)->with('orders')->get();
```

This way you get all data and their related data. i.e the above query will give you the details of the buyers and new property orders which is an array represents all orders belongs to that particular buyer.

Each order also has the property purchases which include the array of objects and each object(i.e purchase object) have product property which represents the details of the product.

As per your query
if you want all order with the buyer and their purchase details(purchase also include product detail).

```
$orders = Order::where('status', 0)->with(['buyer', 'purchases'])->get();
```

and if you want all order with buyer and their purchase's product details.

```
$orders = Order::where('status', 0)->with(['buyer', 'purchases.product'])->get();
print_r($orders);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I didn't want it. See my answer.

Comment: Ok. So tell us what do you want? And did you try my suggestion

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here (status = 0) => not Paid order and (status = 1) => Paid order and always one buyer have only one Not paid order not more. But have more paid orders.

**Buyer.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Buyer extends Model
{

    /**
     * other functions and properties.
     */

    /**
     * Get the orders associated with the buyer.
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'buyer_id')->where('status', 0);
    }
}
```

**Order.php**

```
class Order extends Model
{

    /**
     * other functions and properties.
     */

    /**
     * Get the purchases associated with the Order.
     */
    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

**Purchase.php**

```
class Purchases extends Model
{    
    /**
     * other functions and properties.
     */

    /**
     * Get the user product associated with the Purchase.
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Now query just like this.

```
$order = Order::with(['buyer', 'purchases', 'purchases.product'])->where('id', order_id)->first();
```

Comment: This is the what I suggest you to do. Anyway that's why i told you read the link hat i suggest you so you will find solutions from the document.